# Can I safely substitute a DC converter for the Macbook's AC adapter?

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc-dc-converter, laptop

I want to go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

The converter would be this: http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B00HVCWGNE or something like it.

Does this sound safe?

The step up converter would be set to a specific output voltage and remain there. This bothers me insofar as it relates to a statement on [Ken Sheriff's blog](http://www.righto.com/2013/06/teardown-and-exploration-of-magsafe.html) about Apple's "charger:"

> The charger provides a very low current...6 volt signal on the power pins (3 volts for Magsafe 2).

I don't know if he means the adapter or the connector that plugs into the laptop. I want to make sure all the 3rd parties that already produce something like this don't know something about the 3/6 volts that I don't.

Comment: Did you read this part of the article ? Don't try this at home
Warning: I recommend you don't try any of these experiments. 85 watts is enough to do lots of damage: blow out your Mac's DC input board, send flames out of a component, blow fuses, or vaporize PC traces, and that's just the things I've had happen to me. The Mac and charger both have various protection mechanisms, but they won't take care of everything. Poking at your charger while it's plugged in is a high-risk activity.

Comment: If you have MacBook Air this might work for you $23 http://www.amazon.com/GPK-Car-Charger-Apple-Macbook/dp/B0056PXJ8O (Here you can slice open the car plug if you have to)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this, I would not mess on the Magsafe adapter site.

Instead get one of the commercially available Car charges and there you can slice open the car plug if you have to.

Here is a [example of such product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ETCD9BC)

Doing it your way, you will still need a DC-AC-DC step up from 12 to 14.6 Volt. Furthermore you would have to be very careful with the Magsafe plug and the super small space to work with, and the risks involved.

Comment: I think "my way" that you are referencing is misunderstood. I am talking about using something like this: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00LJXGHC2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very possible. Here's an article that someone wrote up on how he did this:

https://www.bigmessowires.com/2020/04/16/building-a-12v-dc-magsafe-charger/

Answer (score -1):

In theory; yes, in practice; no.

Theorectically, all you need to do is wire the connector so it's sending the correct voltage and current through to the computer. However, this is incredibly difficult to achieve. The people who design the commercial products are professional electrical engineers, who studied for years to do stuff like that, and they're built in factories with strict quality control standards. If a layman were to try to build something like that he'd most likely start a fire of fry his computer. It wouldn't be worth the risk when you could by what you'd need for a relatively low price.